# The multi-part identifier could not be bound(SQl Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Her is the query

```
SELECT NX.FileId, NX.SheetName, NX.SubmitId, NX.SubmitTimeA, NX.UpdateTimeA, NX.UpdateUserId, NX.FileSubmitId, NX.Tags, NX.UserId, NX.FileName, NX.UpdateFirstName, NX.UpdateLastName,  NX.NG, NX.Complete, NX.FirstName, NX.LastName
                                        FROM(
                                             SELECT X.FileId, X.SheetName, X.SubmitId, X.SubmitTimeA, X.UpdateTimeA, X.UpdateUserId, X.FileSubmitId, X.Tags, X.UserId, X.FileName, X.FirstName AS UpdateFirstName, X.LastName AS UpdateLastName, X.NG, X.Complete,  U.FirstName, U.LastName
                                             FROM(
                                                  SELECT SS.FileId, SS.SheetName, SS.SubmitId, SS.SubmitTimeA, SS.UpdateTimeA, SS.UpdateUserId, SS.FileSubmitId, SS.Tags, SS.UserId, SS.FileName, SS.NG, SS.Complete, US.FirstName, US.LastName
                                                  FROM SubmitSheets AS SS
                                                  Left Join Users as US
                                                  ON  SS.UpdateUserId =  US.UserId
                                             ) as X
                                             Left Join Users As U
                                             On X.UserId = U.UserId
                                        ) AS NX
                                        INNER JOIN Files AS F
                                        ON NX.FileId=F.FileId
                                        WHERE F.Locked =0 AND 1=1 AND 1=1 AND 1=1 AND NX.UpdateTimeA >= Cast('2014/10/30'as datetime) AND NX.UpdateTimeA < DateAdd("d", 1, Cast('2014/10/31'as datetime)) AND (1=1) AND SS.Complete=1 OR SS.NG=1
                                        ORDER BY NX.UpdateTimeA DESC
```

Here is the error

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "SS.Complete" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "SS.NG" could not be bound.
```

**Type of NG and Complete field is "bit"**

Comment: @wewesthemenace : No, it didn't worked... the respective inner query is working fine separately..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `SS.Complete` and `SS.NG` with `NX.Complete` and `NX.NG` respectively in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT NX.FileId, NX.SheetName, NX.SubmitId, NX.SubmitTimeA, NX.UpdateTimeA, NX.UpdateUserId, NX.FileSubmitId, NX.Tags, NX.UserId, NX.FileName, NX.UpdateFirstName, NX.UpdateLastName,  NX.NG, NX.Complete, NX.FirstName, NX.LastName
FROM(
     SELECT X.FileId, X.SheetName, X.SubmitId, X.SubmitTimeA, X.UpdateTimeA, X.UpdateUserId, X.FileSubmitId, X.Tags, X.UserId, X.FileName, X.FirstName AS UpdateFirstName, X.LastName AS UpdateLastName, X.NG, X.Complete,  U.FirstName, U.LastName
     FROM(
          SELECT SS.FileId, SS.SheetName, SS.SubmitId, SS.SubmitTimeA, SS.UpdateTimeA, SS.UpdateUserId, SS.FileSubmitId, SS.Tags, SS.UserId, SS.FileName, SS.NG, SS.Complete, US.FirstName, US.LastName
          FROM SubmitSheets AS SS
          Left Join Users as US
          ON  SS.UpdateUserId =  US.UserId
     ) as X
     Left Join Users As U
     On X.UserId = U.UserId
) AS NX
INNER JOIN Files AS F
ON NX.FileId=F.FileId
WHERE F.Locked =0 AND 1=1 AND 1=1 AND 1=1 AND NX.UpdateTimeA >= Cast('2014/10/30'as datetime) AND NX.UpdateTimeA < DateAdd("d", 1, Cast('2014/10/31'as datetime)) AND (1=1) AND NX.Complete=1 OR NX.NG=1
ORDER BY NX.UpdateTimeA DESC
```

Comment: Use `NX.NG` and `NX.Complete`